# Binding Custom Attached Properties from XAML Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, attached-properties

If I do this

```
<StackPanel xmlns:mycode="clr-namespace:mycode">

<TextBlock x:Name="control1"
mycode:foobar.MyText = "Hello world"
>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=control1, Path=(mycode:foobar.MyText)">
```

It throws a HRESULT FAIL Catastrophic, Unexpected, blah blah.

I am missing something?  Does this work?  It works if I specify an attached property from the default xmlpresentation namespace like (Canvas.Left) . Works perfectly.

*DOES THIS WORK IN WINDOWS PHONE 8.0, VISUAL STUDIO 2012?*

Answer (score 0):

HELLLO, EARTH TO STACKOVERFLOW,

Can I bind to a custom attached property on a an element in the XAML?

Comment: are people not using attached properties?. Am i missing something?  Would you just bind to attached property of the 'OTHER' element? It's value of the 'global' attached property is different; RIGHT?